# How to hide UitableviewCell if ad is not available?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am Integrating ads in UITableView.

I have to hide the Cell if ad is not available,Please suggest me the best way to do this-

I have every 6th row as ad in the datasource.

First Method -
Just check the index path then add the ad view in the list.

When I am using this method, I am not able to remove cell if ad is not available,because when removing data from data source, all cells data get changed.

```
if ([_response_data valueForKey:@"mediaType"]] == ADTYPE]) {

 if ([VGVunglePub adIsAvailable]) {
        
        AdViewView *cell = (AdViewView *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        
        if (cell == nil) {
            
            NSArray *topLevelObjects;
            topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AdViewView" owner:self options:nil];
            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                    cell =  (AdViewView *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }             
        return cell;
    }
else {  What i have to here if ad is not available }}
```

Second Method -

Remove the ad details from the datasource and add the view using - [This Link](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/03/embedding-google-admob-ads-within.html)

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: what do you mean all cell data change. You mean they move position?